# Optimizing Drag Operations (Direct2d)

Tags: c++, winapi, optimization, drag-and-drop, direct2d

I am working on a window which displays a number of objects (a graph) (C++/Win32API). This is in GDI+ and I have written a test piece of code with Direct2d as I want to improve the performance when dragging objects in the window. The best approach I have found (to date) is the following (using a graph of 1000 nodes and 999 edges).

(bascially buffer static content to a bitmap buffer and only draw whats moving)
When dragging starts (e.g lbuttondown state), create a base rendertarget with the full graph excluding the node being dragged and the attached edges, call GetBitmap and store for later use. When I need to draw (due to mousemove event and lbuttondown state true), then clear the current hwndrendertarget (background wash white), then draw the edges that are connected to the node being moved into the hwndrendertarget, then copy the save bitmap to the hwndrendertarget, then copy the node bitmap (created when the node is first created in the DB, saves actually drawing it) being moved to the hwndrendertarget, then call EndDraw.

Now this works ok (ish), what I don't like it that, when the node is dragged quickly the mouse cursor moves ahead of the node being dragged (distance depending on speed of drag/mousemove bu worst case up to about 1/2 inch). My reference app is MS Visio, dragging a single object on this shows the cursor staying in the same position over the object being dragged maybe +/- 1/2 pixels.

What I have not tried yet is moving all the (and only) the drawing operations to a separate thread, but before I try this I would like to research other methods if other single threaded approaches would trump this way.

**Update:**
I have optimized this a bit more with improvement, I found I was allocating and de-allocating the edge brush in the draw function which I have moved out to a class wide object and initialize for the life of the class as with other brushes etc. The cursor now only gets a little way (2 pixels or so) outside of the object being dragged when being dragged quickly, the object is a 15px radius circle. so the cursor is able to move up to 17px away from the middle of the object (the point the cursor should stick to) when being dragged. In testing I found an interesting thing, on my main monitor the drag is worse in that the cursor can get ahead of the object being dragged by more than 17px, say up to maybe 25px from the center point of the object where the cursor should be fixed. On the second monitor for the extended desktop (i.e. no taskbar) the drag is better in that described previously. If I hide the taskbar on the main monitor and run the app on that monitor and drag, the performance is the same as the second monitor.

Comment: The normal fix for this is to ignore the mouse coordinates in `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and display the drag image at the real current cursor position (which you can get using `GetCursorPos()`).

Comment: I am already using this method, when the ''WM_MOUSEMOVE'' message is received, I ignore the param and call 'GetCursorPos()' immediately where I perform matrix translations including 'ScreenToClient', then call the draw function as explained above.

Comment: Found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9705363/1904540

        // Create a Direct2D render target.
        hr = m_pDirect2dFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
            D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hwnd, sizeU, D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_IMMEDIATELY),
            &m_pHwndRenderTarget
            );
Required : D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_IMMEDIATELY